# Scroll to last message on collection view is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView that has an input accesory view at the bottom containing a text field and other elements. The app works like a messaging app: you write something and then you send it, at which point the message is added to the collection view.

The problem is that, with the code I've implemented, the "auto scroll" stars working when there is a certain number of messages (items in the collection view), 16-18 is the amount of items you need to add before the auto-scroll stars to work. This is the code I've implemented so far:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    self.inputTextField.text = ""
            
    if self.messages.count > 0 {
       let indexpath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
       self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexpath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

That code is in the `textFieldShouldReturn` method.

This is what I get when I put a breakpoint in the line "self.collectionView?..."

[image]

Comment: it's usual scroll happens when number of items doesn't fit on screen , then where is the problem ?

Comment: the problem is that i want it to scroll when there is no more space in the collection view to show the messages. The message 10-12, from those messages you can't see the other messages until you get to the message 17, then the auto scroll happen. It's like you send 6-7 messages without seeing them, because the autoscroll doesn't happen.